# Linking two classes together

Tags: java, class

I have two classes here that I'm trying to link together but can't get it to work. One is called `smokers` one is called `Pair`.

My compiler is spewing errors saying that it can't find symbol `pair`.

I have placed them both in the same package. Not sure why it isn't registering it.

```
package smokerz;

import java.util.*;


public class smokers{

    //initialise
    //create a node inner class which has the nodes position
    //make 2D array of nodes
    //
    public static void main(String[]args){
        initialise();

    }

    public static void initialise(){
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairedCoordinates = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int line = 0;

        //for board boundaries
        int boardX;
        int boardY;
        while (scan.hasNextLine()){
            //means we're reading the board coordinates
            if (line == 0){
                boardX = scan.nextInt();
                boardY = scan.nextInt();
            }
            int nonSmokersPosX;
            int nonSmokersPosY;
            nonSmokersPosX = scan.nextInt();
            nonSmokersPosY = scan.nextInt();
            pairedCoordinates.add(new Pair(nonSmokersPosX, nonSmokersPosY));
            line++;
        }


package smokerz;

public class Pair<X, Y>{

    private X xcoord;
    private Y ycoord;

    public Pair(X xcoord, Y ycoord){
        this.xcoord = xcoord;
        this.ycoord = ycoord;

    }
    public X getXCoord(){
        return xcoord;
    }

    public Y getYCoord(){
        return ycoord;
    }
    public void setXCoord(X x){
        this.xcoord = x;
    }
    public void setYCoord(Y y){
        this.ycoord = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace.  Using terms like "linking" makes it sound like you are using C++ (ah...the good old days).

Comment: smokers.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Pair
location: class smokerz.smokers
  List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairedCoordinates = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();
       ^
smokers.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Pair
location: class smokerz.smokers
  List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> pairedCoordinates = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();
                                                                 ^
smokers.java:36: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Pair
location: class smokerz.smokers
      pairedCoordinates.add(new Pair(nonSmokersPosX, nonSmokersPosY));

Comment: I'm wanting to create an instance of my pair class in my smokers class.

Comment: add `import smockers.Pair` in the smockers file

Comment: Are you working directly from the command line, or are you using an IDE?

Comment: I'm using command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strong suggestion: name your first class "Smokers" (capital "S").

Q: Did "Pair.java" actually compile?  I suspect not.

Please try compiling "Pair", and please update your post with the error message (if applicable).

======================================================

ADDENDUM:

It just occurred to me what's going wrong - you're using packages (good!), but you're forgetting to take them into consideration when you compile from the command line (something an IDE would do for you automagically).

Please do this:

1) `mkdir smokerz  # Create a subdirectory for your Java package`

2) `cp smokers.java Pair.java smokerz  # Copy your source to "smokerz"`

3) `javac smokerz\Pair.java  # Compile your two files in the directory *above*`

`javac smokerz\smokers.java`

4) Run your program

`java smokerz.smokers`

Look here for more details:

http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html

Comment: The Pair class compiled. When I compile the Smokers class it comes up with the error messages in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be because you have your initialise() as static. If it doesn't have to be static, take static out and try that.

Comment: This should not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The smokers class needs at least two }'s at the end of it to finish the code.

The package for pair doesn't need a ; after it.

Perhaps the split between files in your code isn't made clear in the question.